# Change the layout view on the click of the Item

Tags: android, xml

The app has been designed using RecyclerView, in which the Linear Layout which contain the progress bar.

I want to change the view when item is been clicked, and when item has been clicked then that item which is been clicked should look big in same position as compared to another item. On click, suppose I get number 20 then progress bar color should change up to 20% different color and remaining should be in different color.

Main.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

list.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llDevice"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbBatteryStatus"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminateOnly="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/border_progressbar"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

border_progressbar.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        <gradient
            android:centerColor="@color/ripple_grey"
            android:endColor="@color/ripple_grey"
            android:startColor="@color/ripple_grey" />
    </shape>
</item>


<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/ripple_errorMsg"
                android:startColor="@color/ripple_color" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a flag in your model

```
boolean clicked = false;
```

then when an item clicked in your list you should change it's clicked status

```
model.clicked = !model.clicked;
```

then in `onBindViewHolder` with a simple if and else you can change the view of items with `true` clicked status

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      Model model = models.get(position);
      if(model.clicked){}
      else{}
}
```